# When should an http.RoundTripper close its connection?

Tags: http, go

I'm using [httputil.ReverseProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy) with an [http.RoundTripper](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) of my own implementation that uses an [ssh.Channel](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Channel) as a transport. My RoundTrip method looks approximately like this:

```
func (c SSHConnection) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    ch, err := c.GetChannel()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("couldn't open forwarded-tcpip channel: " + err.Error())
    }
    // defer ch.Close()
    err = req.Write(ch)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("couldn't send request: " + err.Error())
    }

    return http.ReadResponse(bufio.NewReader(ch), req)
}

func (c SSHConnection) GetChannel() (ssh.Channel, error) {
    ch, req, err := c.Conn.OpenChannel("forwarded-tcpip", msg)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    go ssh.DiscardRequests(req)
    return ch, nil
}
```

Notice the commented-out defer ch.Close(). Initially I naively closed the connection here, but the response body would sometimes be empty, due to a race between the HTTP proxy's reading of the body and this closing of the SSH channel.

Assuming, for now, that I don't care to do keep-alive, when can I close the ssh.Channel? If I don't, every request starts a new goroutine (because of go ssh.DiscardRequests(req)), so I leak a goroutine on every HTTP requests until the underlying SSH connection is closed.

Comment: I haven't thought this through, but Response.Body is just an io.ReadCloser. Maybe you can wrap the default's Close() method. Then you'll know when the caller is done with the response and you can close the connection.

Comment: Yes, It's up to the client to consume and close the `Response.Body`, but closing it doesn't directly close the connection, it only releases it from the body. I think if you want to handle the connection at this layer, rather than at the transport layer, you will need to buffer the entire response and close your connection within RoundTrip. Is there a reason you're not using ssh simply as a network transport?

Comment: @Peter Good idea; implemented and working. Maybe worth making an answer?

Comment: @JimB Would you mind explaining a little more? I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "transport layer" or "using ssh simply as a network transport."

Comment: @TrevorDixon: The "RoundTripper" (almost always a `Transport`) is meant to handle the connection lifetimes outside of `RoundTrip`. The connection is closed at some point after the body is consumed, usually initiated by the server, and that may be long after `RoundTrip` returns. The http request (aka "RoundTrip") and connection handling happen at different conceptual layers. The ssh connection is acting as a network proxy, so to work properly, it needs to be hooked in at that level just like you would with an http or socks proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `http.RoundTripper` should not close the connection until after the response body has been fully consumed, or at the request of the server.

The simplest option is to fully buffer the response and close the connection immediately. In some cases this may actually be the most efficient, if the traffic mostly consists of small, independent requests.

The next option is to hook the closing of the response body to close the channel.

```
type Body struct {
    io.ReadCloser
    channel ssh.Channel
}

func (b *Body) Close() error {
    b.channel.Close()
    return b.ReadCloser.Close()
}

func (c SSHConnection) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    ch, err := c.GetChannel()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("couldn't open forwarded-tcpip channel: " + err.Error())
    }

    err = req.Write(ch)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("couldn't send request: " + err.Error())
    }

    resp, err := http.ReadResponse(bufio.NewReader(ch), req)
    if err != nil {
        ch.Close()
        return nil, err
    }

    resp.Body = &Body{
        ReadCloser: resp.Body,
        channel:    ch,
    }
    return resp, err
}
```

Lastly, to make the most efficient use of the ssh channels, you could use an existing `Transport` with a `net.Dialer` which makes the ssh connection, and wraps the channel in a `net.Conn` interface.